# ASP.NET Core 2 with Angular (Angular Universal)

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, angular-universal

ASP.NET Core 2 with Angular doesn't come with Angular Universal so now there are 3 app.module files in Angular. I am able to use them and I know the differences among these app.modules (server, browser and the standard one). However I am curious if there is a valid technical or non technical reason why did MS chose to abandon Angular Universal (when creating new standalone Angular project from Angular CLI it uses Angular Universal so it looks like only MS is doing it differently).

Comment: ASP.NET Core and Angular Universal fill the same role (they are HTTP servers), why would you need both?

Comment: well I think that there is some reason for it...

from official Angular Universal website:

Angular Universal was originally built to work with a node.js back-end. There are adapters for most popular node.js server-side frameworks such as Express or Hapi.js. In addition to node.js, however, Angular Universal has ASP.NET Core support. In the near future we hope to add support for Java, PHP and Python.

Comment: You are correct, I misunderstood its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[perfomance check](http://%20https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/654#issuecomment-350037107)

Rendered components on page         1   60  600 1800

.NET – response (ms)                9   15  42  113

Express (NodeJS) – response (ms)    5   9   33  99

.NET slower by                     80%  67% 27% 14%

.Net with Angular Universal use node for render server-side HTML page and I don't recommend use .net with Angular Universal.

I recommendation use a .net core WEB API and Angular Universal(Node.js)